# JOIN the Strings of different textboxes and again SPLIT

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am new in vb.net, so not much familiar with all VB functions. While working on 1 Windows Application, while taking order we need to save product and its specification like weight, height, width, color, length, material etc.
since every product can have different specification so its is not possible to determine and provide for fields in database.

So, I decided to provide textboxes so user can enter name & value while entering product details. 1 textbox for name & other textbox for value. 
like this

```
Textbox1 = "WEIGHT"     TextBox2 = "10" '(Value of Weight)
Textbox3 = "WIDTH"      TextBox4 = "5" '(value of Width)
Textbox4 = "LENGTH"      TextBox5 = "5" '(Value of Length)
```

(All these textboxes are dynamically created in Groupbox "GBox1")

Instead of saving product specification in separate column. I want to save these names & values as String e.g. "WEIGHT=10;WIDTH=5;LENGTH=5" in SQL Database(TEXT OR VARCHAR field). Because we dnt want any calculations or search etc. on this. just customer requirements to book order & save in Database for future records.

Then again While calling or editing Product SPLIT the string as separate fields, String Before = Separate & string after = separate, then display all names & their corresponding values in Textboxes (as Displayed while adding) so user can edit and after changes again save as single string value.

After search I found SPLIT & JOIN functions for this purpose.
need some help in using these functions in Loop to merge string from textboxes 
for each loop to read all textboxes in Groupbox

```
Dim ItemList As New ArrayList()
Dim PrDetails As String
For Each Ctrl As Control In GBox1.Controls
    If TypeOf Ctrl Is TextBox Then
        ItemList.Add(CType(Ctrl, TextBox).Text)
    End If
Next
PrDetails = String.Join()
```

How to perform join on these array list? and again SPLIT this pattern while retrieving from Database.

Also need suggestions regarding this approach or any other way to implement. Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of work. In the approach you're taking, if you want to sort by one or more of those attributes, it's going to be really painful. Maybe you need a table with product specs?

Comment: `ArrayList`s are old and not type specific please consider a `List(Of String)` instead.

Comment: I would look into saving the data as XML. If you are using SQL Server (or some other top names) you will be able to query this info right from the database as well.

Comment: how in the world does gluing a string together and chopping it up to get integral information save anything at all, anywhere?  what "calculations" are you talking about?  If H, W, Wt have meaning to the app they ought not be converted to string *and* glued together.

Comment: But, to answer your question, you should use SPLIT and JOIN. I would have 2 reserved characters (that users cannot type). 1 for splitting your controls (Name/Value pairs) and then 1 for splitting the name and value.

Comment: "I am new in vb.net" for the love of god, buy a book

Comment: @Verdolino: most of books explain only basic functions they do not provide for this type of practical problems. such problems arise when we start practice actual work. "For the Love of God" *these type of Forums are here to discuss & take suggestions of experts in the field!* :)

Comment: The books would not tell you do do it this way. The reason you were stuck is because your design is really bad. See my solution below, which is overly complicated because the design is so bad. You're welcome.

Comment: that textbox example I give only as example because i want to highlight main problem only that is SPLIT & JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this solution to work, you will need to accept the fact that there needs to be *some* amount of standardization to your solution. `TextBox1` and `TextBox3` won't work as names, so I used `txtName1` and `txtValue1` etc. To test this solution, make a new form, put `GroupBox1`, paste the code in the class and run.

```vb
Private nameTextBoxName = "txtName" ' name textbox prefix
Private valueTextBoxName = "txtValue" ' value textbox prefix
Private paramSeparator = ";" ' between sets of parameters
Private nameAndValueSeparator = "=" ' between name and value
Private xOffset = 10 ' for horizontal spacing inside the groupbox
Private yOffset = 20 ' for vertical spacing inside the groupbox

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' your example data
    Dim testString = "WEIGHT=10;WIDTH=5;LENGTH=5"
    ' set the textboxes
    setTextBoxes(testString)
    ' get the string from the textboxes
    Dim result = getTextBoxesString()
End Sub

' call to get a string with all the data from the textboxes
Private Function getTextBoxesString() As String
    Dim stringToDatabase = ""
    Dim textBoxes = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of Control).
        Where(Function(co As Control) TypeOf co Is TextBox).
        Select(Of TextBox)(Function(co As Control) CType(co, TextBox))
    Dim nameTextBoxes = textBoxes.Where(Function(co As Control) co.Name.Contains(nameTextBoxName))
    Dim valueTextBoxes = textBoxes.Where(Function(co As Control) co.Name.Contains(valueTextBoxName))
    stringToDatabase = nameTextBoxes.Select(Of String)(
        Function(nameTextBox As TextBox)
            Dim valueTextBox = valueTextBoxes.
                Where(Function(vtb As TextBox) vtb.Name = nameTextBox.Name.Replace(nameTextBoxName, valueTextBoxName)).
                First()
            Return nameTextBox.Text & nameAndValueSeparator & valueTextBox.Text
        End Function).Aggregate(Function(oldValue, newValue) oldValue & paramSeparator & newValue)
    Return stringToDatabase
End Function

' call to set the textboxes inside the groupbox based on the data string
Private Sub setTextBoxes(textBoxesString As String)
    Dim params = textBoxesString.Split(paramSeparator)
    Dim index = 1
    GroupBox1.Controls.Clear()
    For Each param In params
        Dim nameAndValue = param.Split(nameAndValueSeparator)
        Dim nameTextBox As New TextBox With
            {.Name = nameTextBoxName & index.ToString(),
             .Text = nameAndValue(0),
             .Location = New Point(xOffset, (index - 1) * .Height + yOffset)}
        Dim valueTextBox As New TextBox With
            {.Name = valueTextBoxName & index.ToString(),
             .Text = nameAndValue(1),
             .Location = New Point(.Width + xOffset, (index - 1) * .Height + yOffset)}
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(nameTextBox)
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(valueTextBox)
        index += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: its working perfect, with some modifications m able to implement in my form :)